# Multi-user HTML Quiz

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic

Has anybody successfully had a go at creating a multi-user quiz in HTML/Javascript/Server Side script whereby the status of each user (bit like a who's 5th, 4th, 3rd, 2nd and 1st) is constantly fed back to each user as they all play the quiz?

I'm not looking to do anything mind blowing and I'm thinking that it's probably all down to just querying a central DB every 'x' number of seconds in the page (eg xhttp), but would really appreciate the opinion of the experts on here :)

Thanks

Comment: It's certainly possible to build something like that but your question is really too broad/unclear. You could use websockets / Socket.IO if there is any need for real-time, bidirectional and event-based communication.

Comment: Hi, the concept would basically be 2 - 10 people would be answering questions on their own web page and as they do this a small part of the page (literally a div container) would state what position each person was at the time, eg player 1 currently has 7 questions right she is 1st, player 2 currently has 5 questions right he is 2nd, player 3 currently has 4 questions right he is 3rd.  After a few more questions, player 3 has 6 questions right so he goes into 2nd and player 2's page shows that he is 3rd - all of this until the quiz timer ends

Comment: At the moment, I'm under the impression that a timer on each page would do a xhttp request (via js) to update the div with the current leader board order - but would this be too much of a hit if there are questions popping up, a timer counting down, etc

Comment: Like I said, it's certainly possible and you could likely build this is different ways. If you use websockets as example, the server can broadcast messages to the clients and vice versa in realtime.

Comment: would web sockets be a better option than a timed xhttp request?  Are they doing something different to the latter?  I'm always keen to work on the base level, ie javascript rather than jquery for my own understanding and to keep it as lean as poss

Comment: You can probably eliminate the need for timers with websockets. The server can broadcast to all the clients when something changes like a score change or answer, likewise the clients can update the server in realtime with the answer/choice the user made.

Comment: My problem is that I'm still working in classic asp and I don't think this can cope with websockets - are timed ajax requests my only option?

Comment: I think it's more down to your own personal preference. I found this post which suggests theres no technical reason you can't use websockets https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318895/how-to-integrate-websockets-on-top-of-a-classic-asp-web-application.